# Ayuda con select SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Tengo una sistema en c# y un motor de bd SQL Server 2014 en el cual el usuario debera hacer una busqueda por Nombre a la siguiente tabla:

```
ID      Nombre
00597   ALBERTO CAMACHO LOPEZ
00598   FRANCISCO MENDOZA TORREZ
00599   JOSE ANGEL MENDOZA TORRES
00600   JOSE EBERARDO HERNANDEZ RODRIGUEZ
00601   LUZ MARQUEZ CRUZ
00602   RAYMUNDO ALVAREZ RUIZ
00603   ISIDRO CAMACHO ORTIZ
00604   LUZ MARIA ALVAREZ GONZALEZ
00605   ANGEL RODRIGUEZ RUIZ
00606   FERNANDO MIGUEL RODRIGUEZ GARCIA
```

El problema es que el usuario no se sabe los nombre completos, es decir si en el cuadro de busqueda escribe 'MENDOZA' deberan aparecer todos los MENDOZA o si escribe 'JOSE' deberan salir todos los JOSE.

Si escribo mi query asi no me arroja ningun resultado, existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

```
SELECT * from Personas where Nombre like 'JOSE'
```

Comment: Y por favor, aclara que motor de base de datos estas usando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de que estés utilizando MySQL o MariaDB, puedes hacer uso del operador comparador `LIKE` y luego del *wildcard* `%`, el cual indica que marcará con cualquier cantidad arbitraria de caracteres. Es como el asterisco `*` en un glob o un `.*` en una expresión regular.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Personas
WHERE 
    nombre LIKE 'jose%'

...
idPersonas    nombre
00599         JOSE ANGEL MENDOZA TORRES
00600         JOSE EBERARDO HERNANDEZ RODRIGUEZ
```

O puedes hacer uso de una expresión regular con `REGEXP`

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Personas
WHERE 
    nombre REGEXP 'Angel.*'

...
idPersonas    nombre
00599         JOSE ANGEL MENDOZA TORRES
00605         ANGEL RODRIGUEZ RUIZ
```

Puedes encontrar mucha información en la documentación oficial.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regular-expressions-overview/

Como se actualizó el tag a `sql-server` y por sugerencia de @gbianchi, pongo en enlace de la documentación de `LIKE` de T-SQL, que prácticamente funciona de la misma manera que en MySQL o MariaDB.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Para otra respuesta, ojo que no aclara la db. y esto puede variar segun la db que use ;)

Comment: lol, tengo la muy mala costumbre de pensar que todo lo "sql" es "mysql". Gracias, deja lo aclaro.

Comment: Ninguno de esos enlaces sirve. OP usa sqlserver. (mas alla que es lo mismo) podrias buscar los enlaces a sql server ?